# Hiding routes on url Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular-router

So I am trying to hide my routes on the url, that means i want my app to show always the url as being in the root app, for example:

> "www.foo.com"

instead of

> "www.foo.com/login"

Its there any way to achieve this in angular 2?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034009/dynamically-change-components-but-have-same-url-displayed-on-address-bar

Comment: Thanks, searched for other answers but couldnt find one

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you are looking for is Angulars `skipLocationChange`, this is what Angular refers to as "NavigationExtras". Here is the documentation: [Angular docs on NavExtras](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras)

```
// Navigate silently to /view
this.router.navigate(['/view'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

Comment: Can we do this with Java on back end? The front end is doing _window.open(url, '_blank')_ where URL has a parameter attached & I have to receive this GET URL on Java controller, but I don't want that token to be viewable on browser.