# How to hide navigation url Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic4

I use **Ionic 4** and **angular 7**

I would like to hide the url of the pages when I browse the web application

in my app have this and the url is visible

[image: the url is visible]

[image]

the result that I would like to obtain is the following:

[image]

thank you

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49410099/5909026

Comment: this example not work in a tab

Answer (score 2):

In that case you can use the [skipLocationChange](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras) property.

Example:

```
this.router.navigate(['/yourview'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

Comment: this work if navigate in pages,  but not work in a tab

Answer (score 1):

You cant hide the address/url bar on web, since its a  intended behaviour.
One option you could think of is fake it :Auto-hide the browser

> window.scrollTo(0,1);