# Hide URL for Named oulets

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am working in a page that have two oulets for data route. The issue is that, after making it work, the route is something like (routename:value).

So in my case I want that when the user goes to /Fligth both routes get the value of "Fligth" and therefore both display the corresponding component.

I have reach this option:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [


{
  path: "groups", 
  component: HomeComponent,
    children:[
  { 
    path: "", 
    redirectTo:"/groups(form:groups)",
    pathMatch:'prefix'
  },
  ] 
},

{
  path: "groups",
  component: GroupRequestFormComponent, 
  outlet:"form"
},

{
  path: "flight",  
  component: HomeComponent,
  children:[
  { 
    path: "", 
    redirectTo:"/flight(form:flight)",
    pathMatch:'prefix'
  },
  ] 
},
{ 
  path: "flight",
  component: flightsSearchFormComponent,
  outlet:"form"
},

{
  path: "hotel",  
  component: HomeComponent,
    children:[
  { 
    path: "", 
    redirectTo:"/hotel(form:hotel)",
    pathMatch:'prefix'
  },
  ] 
},
{
  path: "hotel",
  component: HotelSearchFormApiComponent, 
  outlet:"form"
},



{ 
  path: 'hotel/rate',      
  component:  RatesComponent 
},
{ 
  path: 'hotel/:countryCod/:stateCod/:cityCod/:dateFrom/:dateTo', 
  component:  SearchHotelResultComponent 
},
{
  path: "**",  
  redirectTo:"hotel"
},
  ];
```

it is working as expected, so the user goes to Hotel and it is redirected to /Hotel(form:hotel)

The thing that I want to know now is if I can prevent the URL to be changed on the URL, so it keep as /Hotel.

Thanks.
Andrés

Comment: Looks like your problem has been solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034009/dynamically-change-components-but-have-same-url-displayed-on-address-bar

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved it like this:

APP.COMPONENT.TS Constructor

```
this.router.events.subscribe(routerEvent => {
        if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
            switch (routerEvent.url) {
                case "/hotel":
                    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: {primary: 'hotel',form: 'hotel' } }], {skipLocationChange: true})
                    break;
                case "/flight":
                    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: {primary: 'flight',form: 'flight' } }], {skipLocationChange: true})
                    break;
                case "/groups":
                    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: {primary: 'groups',form: 'groups' } }], {skipLocationChange: true})
                    break;

             } 
        }
    });
```